# Extending jQuery, including the jQuery constructor in another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-plugins, sinemacula

### Explanation

Firstly, I might be mixed up between the jQuery `constructor` and `init` functions, if so please ignore my terminology below.

I have an object called `SineMacula`, which, at the moment is simply acting as a namespace for a library of methods.

However, I am about to write some methods for the `SineMacula` object which I would like to act like jQuery extensions.

The complication arises here, instead of using the jQuery alias `$`, I would like to use the `SineMacula` object to run the jQuery construct. So effectively my code will look like this:

```
SineMacula('#test').dropdown();
```

instead of:

```
$('#test').dropdown();
```

**However,** I don't think this would be too hard if it wasn't for my next point:

**I do not want to alias the whole of jQuery, I simply want the jQuery constructor to run when I call `SineMacula('something')`, and then apply any methods to the result of `SineMacula('something')`**

### My Question

The best way to ask this question is by illustrating. Is the following possible?

```
SineMacula('#test').someFunction(function(){
    // Do something here
    // The jQuery object must be passed in so that
    // $(this) refers to SineMacula('#test')
});
```

However, I do **not** want to be able to do this (fully alias jQuery):

```
SineMacula('#test').animate(); // A regular jQuery function
```

I am aware this is probably not possible, but felt it was worth asking :-)

### UPDATE 1

Just to be clear, this is some of the code I am currently using for the `SineMacula` object:

```
/**
 * Sine Macula Javascript  API
 * The Sine Macula API contains all base functions for use throughout
 * all websites
 * @name class.sinemacula.js
 * @author Ben Carey
 * @version 1.0
 * @date 25/10/2012
 * @copyright (c) 2012 Sine Macula MMVIII Limited (sinemacula.co.uk)
 */

function SineMacula(){

    // Only proceed if jQuery has been loaded
    if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){
        // jQuery has not been loaded
        console.log('jQuery has not been loaded');
    }else{

        /**
         * Sine Macula Load
         * Load the Sine Macula Libraries and Plugins
         * into the current document
         *
         * The options:
         * - package: the package of libraries to load
         * - packageURL: a remote source to load the package details from
         * - libraries: any additional libraries to load
         *
         * @param object options The options for the Sine Macula load
         */
        this.load = function(options){
            // Load Sine Macula Libraries here
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Overlay
 * Place an overlay on the page
 *
 * The options:
 * - wrapper: the wrapper to prepend to
 * - fade: indicate whether or not to fade the overlay
 * - fadeSpeed: the fade speed for the overlay fade
 * - opacity: the opacity to apply to the overlay
 * - color: the color to apply to the overlay
 * - callback: the callback to be called once the function has completed
 *
 * @param boolean showHide A boolean to indicate whether to show/hide the overlay
 * @param object options The options for the overlay
 */
SineMacula.prototype.overlay = function (showHide,options){
    // Process the overlay here
};

// All libraries are extended onto the SineMacula object
```

The `SineMacula` object is initiated at the top of each page like so:

```
<script src="//libraries.example.net/jsapi" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var sm = new SineMacula();
    sm.load();

</script>
```

---

### UPDATE 2 - Ignore Above

Right, I am finding it very hard to explain what I would like to achieve. I will do my best to accomplish this below in steps, ignore the content above.

**Step 1**

I have a class called `SineMacula`, this contains many methods that do all sorts of things. Think of it as a library like jQuery.

This is defined like so:

```
function SineMacula(){

    // Only proceed if jQuery has been loaded
    if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){
        // jQuery has not been loaded
        console.log('jQuery has not been loaded');
    }else{
        this.load = function(options){
            // Load Sine Macula Libraries here
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 2**

The `SineMacula` class is initiated at the top of each page with the following code:

```
<script src="//libraries.example.net/jsapi" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var sm = new SineMacula();

</script>
```

**Step 3**

The `SineMacula` object then loads any required libraries and extensions for the `SineMacula` object by calling e.g. `sm.load({package:'all'})`. This will dynamically load any extensions into the webpage.

**Step 4**

The extensions are defined like so:

```
SineMacula.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    // Do something here
}
```

**Step 5 - This is where things get a little more complex**

Up until now, the `SineMacula` object has been acting as a namespace for methods such as `doSomething()` etc.

I would now like to define methods that do more than just act as a function.

Where I would have called `SineMacula.doSomething()`, I would now like to **be able** to call `SineMacula('#test').doSomething()` where `SineMacula('#test')` acts the same as `$('#test')` in jQuery.

So I can access my functions like this:

```
SineMacula.doSomething('maybe parameters here');
SineMacula('selector').doSomethingElse('maybe parameters here');
```

In the same way that you can call:

```
$.ajax('parameters');
$('selector').animate('parameters');
```

So **if** an argument is passed to the `SineMacula` object then it is processed using the jQuery *selector* function and passed as the subject to the method being called.

For example:

```
// Call doSomethingElse on the #test element
SineMacula('#test').doSomethingElse();

// Within the doSomethingElse function $(this) relates to $('#test')
```

**To summarise...**

`SineMacula('selector')` acts as `$('selector')` if `'selector'` is supplied, and this gets passed to the child method. But `SineMacula` is not an extension of jQuery. I do not want `SineMacula` to be an Alias of `$`.

Comment: But `load` is a jquery method too. What happens? complete override?

Comment: Re your edit: You have to decide whether you want to call `SineMacula` directly, as in your earlier examples, or using `new`, as in the code posted in your update. That decision fundamentally affects how you structure things.

Comment: `SineMacula` is not an extension of the whole jQuery object, therefore the load function does not collide. I only want the selector function to be passed into `SineMacula` :-)

Comment: You're creating an *instance* with `var sm = new SineMacula();` and then initializing it separately via `sm.load(...);`. But then in your examples, you never use it again. Why create the instance? Why is creating an instance a separate step from initializing things? Why do you never use that instance (`sm`) again, instead going back to the constructor function? I hate to say it, but even as of Update 2, this still doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand the question and if you can change `SineMacula` constructor

```
function SineMacula(){
     // add following 3 lines
     if(arguments.length>0) {
        return jQuery.call(null,arguments);
     }
    // Only proceed if jQuery has been loaded
    if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){
        // jQuery has not been loaded
        console.log('jQuery has not been loaded');
    }else{

        this.load = function(options){
            // Load Sine Macula Libraries here
            console.log("ok load");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Will that then pass the `SineMacula('#test')` object into any method called like `SineMacula('#test').doSomething()`?